# Django ModelForm, how to add fields from serializer class

Tags: python, django, serialization

I'm working on a ModelForm class and in this class I need to add some extra fields that exist in django rest framework serializer class. My code below:

```
class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['title', ]

    def __init__(self, serializer_class, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        serializer = serializer_class()
        for name in serializer.fields:
            self.fields.update({name: serializer.fields[name]})
```

The line `self.fields.update({name: serializer.fields[name]})` doesn't work properly because the serializer field doesn't have properties like widget, etc...

Does anyone know a way to parse a serializer field into a form field? I know that you can use [DRF to render forms](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/), it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for any help